# Windows common folder

Tags: windows, directory, allusersprofile

Does the env. variable ALLUSERSPROFILE and the function

```
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, path, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, FALSE)
```

Will always lead to the same path (in all Windows versions)?

I need this because our installer uses the env. variable and in our code we use 
the function call.

Thanks

Comment: So far as I can tell, the paths will be the same. But I can't find documentation to support that.

Comment: Environment variables can be changed easily.  So no, technically you're not safe.  Practically you can blame the user for doing something silly.  Do favor MSI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function and enviromental varibale will be same path. Im not sure if they will both be the same string on all versions of windows, IE one could produce a "DOS path".

Folder is likely to change between versions of windows and windows install language.

Testing on Windows 7 and XP both seem to produce a long path name ( IE above 8 chars )